# How to sort an excel file in ascending order by age

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to sort the excel file in ascending order by age (ani how you will find in the code).I tired to do this with pandas, openpyxl, win32com.client etc, and nothing is working and I don't know why. In the code that I will add here I tried to sort with openpyxl the forth column of the excel file.

Here is the code:

```
#### AICI BAGI TOATE FUNCTIILE ####
def add(ws1,ws2):


    nume = text.get(1.14, "2.0-1c")
    cnp = text.get(1.0, 1.13)
    global club
    club = text.get(2.0, 'end-1c')
    c_cnp = cnp

    
    varsta = int(c_cnp)/10000000000%100
    x = 1999 + varsta
    ani = 2022 - x

    an_nastere = int(c_cnp)/10000000000%100 + 2000
    luna_nastere = int(c_cnp)/100000000%100
    zi_nastere = int(c_cnp)/1000000%100

    # Data de nastere comparata cu data de azi
    data_azi = datetime.date.today()
    current_year = datetime.date.today().year
    data_sportiv = datetime.date(current_year, int(luna_nastere), int(zi_nastere))

    # Compara data de azi cu data de nastere a sportivului
    if data_sportiv > data_azi:
        ani = ani - 1

    ##CONTACT LEGITIMATIE QR
    contact = f'Nume: {nume}\nVarsta: {str(int(ani))}\nClub: {club}'

    ## AICI SCRIE IN FISIER ##
    if cnp.startswith('5') is True:
        print("merge")

        img = qrcode.make(contact)  ##### IMPORTANT
        img.save(nume + ".png")

        if var14.get() == 1:
            ws1.append([cnp, nume, club, str(int(ani)) + ' ani',str(int(zi_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(luna_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(an_nastere)), 'Stagiu'])
        else:
            ws1.append([cnp, nume, club, str(int(ani)) + ' ani', str(int(zi_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(luna_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(an_nastere)),aviz , str(proba1), str(proba2), str(proba3), str(proba4),
                str(proba5), str(proba6), str(proba7), str(proba8), str(proba9), str(proba10), str(proba11) ,str(proba12), '\n'])


    elif cnp.startswith('6') == True:
        print("merge fete")

        img = qrcode.make(contact)
        img.save(nume + ".png")

        if var14.get() == 1:
            ws1.append([cnp, nume, club, str(int(ani)) + ' ani',str(int(zi_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(luna_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(an_nastere)), 'Stagiu'])

        else:
            ws2.append([cnp, nume, club, str(int(ani)) + ' ani', str(int(zi_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(luna_nastere)) + '.' + str(int(an_nastere)),aviz ,str(proba1), str(proba2), str(proba3), str(proba4),
                        str(proba5), str(proba6), str(proba7), str(proba8), str(proba9), str(proba10), str(proba11) ,str(proba12), '\n'])


    ws1.auto_filter.add_filter_column(3,['ani'])
    ws1.auto_filter.add_sort_condition("D1:D150")

    wb.save("Inscriere Sportivi.xlsx")
```

And here its the output file:
[image: The output file]

Comment: This is a really a lot more code than necessary for the question. Can you reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem? I.e., please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ANY TIME you find yourself with a set of variables like `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3` etc., you need to replace that set with a list.  All that code you have doing something 12 times, you can just do it once in a loop.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us the data you're trying to handle, we could suggest a better way.  You do know that Excel has a built-in sort feature, yes?

Comment: Yes i know but I want to do it as i add the data so when the file is created te data is already sorted

Answer (score 0):

Just save your excel file, then open, sort and save again.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by="Age", ascending=True)
with pd.ExcelWriter('./Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    df_sorted.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Before

# Row Col1 Col2  Col3  Age
# 0   123  asd   zxc    2
# 1   234  asd   asd    6
# 2  2345  xxx   vvb    3
# 3   363  zxc   ddd    4
# 4    56  asd   ddd    1
# 5   234  vvb  gghg    5
# 6     6  ddd    ad    4

# After

# Row Col1 Col2  Col3  Age
# 0   234  asd   asd    6
# 1   234  vvb  gghg    5
# 2   363  zxc   ddd    4
# 3     6  ddd    ad    4
# 4  2345  xxx   vvb    3
# 5   123  asd   zxc    2
# 6    56  asd   ddd    1
```

[Google Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ckar6YFW9IHDYYeQw0OqlL28ogMVKdGdAKTaaVPgcYs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The excel isn't sorted and the first row of the excel is with bold.

Answer (score 0):

[@Vitaly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11279769/vitaliy-korolyk) Solved your issue in the most practical way! However, here's some code and logic improvements, as well as a Pandas way of doing it.

As already mentioned, your code is not reduced to a point where it is easy to help you.

- In addition is not written in English which makes it even harder. I'm currently in Italy and I've been a cyclist so I guess it is a way of giving back :).
- I also presume that `text` is either a Dict, a Series or a DataFrame you're iterating.
- You're doing QR codes regardless of the if/elif condition. If the contact is only for that purpose, then stick the code together.
- You're doing very similar stuff within the if loop.
- Double check if you want to put on ws1 the else condition if cnp starts with 5.

```py
import pandas as pd

def add(ws1, ws2): # ws1 and ws2 must be the sheet_names
    file_with_data = 'This should be the data file'

    # Complete for all the columns you will ever need
    result_dataframe_w1 = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=['CNP', 'Nume', 'Club', 'Età', 'etc...'])
    result_dataframe_w2 = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=['CNP', 'Nume', 'Club', 'Età', 'etc...'])  # Same as Above

    for text in file_with_data: #assuming that you're iterating over a file
        nume = text.get(1.14, "2.0-1c")
        cnp = text.get(1.0, 1.13)

        global club
        club = text.get(2.0, 'end-1c')
        c_cnp = int(cnp)  # Avoid to call int method every time

        varsta = c_cnp/10000000000 % 100
        x = 1999 + varsta  # don't name a variable x, give it a meaningful name
        ani = int(2022 - x)  # Store the Int Already

        # You only seem to care about integers so store them already
        an_nastere = int(c_cnp/10000000000 % 100 + 2000)
        luna_nastere = int(c_cnp/100000000 % 100)
        zi_nastere = int(c_cnp/1000000 % 100)

        # Data de nastere comparata cu data de azi
        data_azi = datetime.date.today()
        current_year = datetime.date.today().year
        data_sportiv = datetime.date(current_year, luna_nastere, zi_nastere)

        # Compara data de azi cu data de nastere a sportivului
        if data_sportiv > data_azi:
            ani -= 1

        # No need to check 'is true'

        # Var 14 Comes from nowhere in your example. You can reverse the loop
        # If var14 is equal to 1, it will go to wb1 regardless of the code
        var14 = "something that we don't know"

        # Only Needed if you only want to generate the contacts under this condition
        if (cnp.startswith('5') or cnp.startswith('6')):

            # CONTACT LEGITIMATIE QR
            contact = f'Nume: {nume}\nVarsta: {str(int(ani))}\nClub: {club}'
            img = qrcode.make(contact)  # IMPORTANT
            img.save(f"{nume}.png")

            if var14.get() == 1:
                athlete_info = pd.Series(
                    [cnp, nume, club, f"{ani} ani", f"{zi_nastere}.{luna_nastere}.{an_nastere}", 'Stagiu'])
                result_dataframe_w1 = pd.concat(
                    [result_dataframe_w1, athlete_info], axis='rows')
            else:
                athlete_info = pd.Series([cnp, nume, club, f"{ani} ani", 
                                          f"{zi_nastere}.{luna_nastere}.{an_nastere}",
                                          aviz, proba1, proba2, proba3,proba4, proba5,
                                          proba6, proba7, proba8, proba9, proba10,
                                          proba11, proba12],dtype=str)
                if cnp.startswith('6'):
                    result_dataframe_w2 = pd.concat(
                        [result_dataframe_w2, athlete_info], axis='rows')
                else:
                    result_dataframe_w1 = pd.concat(
                        [result_dataframe_w1, athlete_info], axis='rows')

    # It does not make much sense to keep the ani word as you will struggle for cumputations but it is possible.
    # Replace Etá by the name of the column assigned above!
    result_dataframe_w1.sort_values('Etá', key=lambda x: int(
        x.replace(' ani', '').strip()), inplace=True)
    result_dataframe_w2.sort_values('Etá', key=lambda x: int(
        x.replace(' ani', '').strip()), inplace=True)

    with pd.ExcelWriter("Inscriere Sportivi.xlsx") as writer:
        result_dataframe_w1.to_excel(
            writer, sheet_name=ws1, index=False)
        result_dataframe_w2.to_excel(
            writer, sheet_name=ws2, index=False)
        writer.save("Inscriere Sportivi.xlsx")
```

Comment: I tried this option, and many other but nothing is working. Sometimes i get an error and sometimes the excel isn't sorted

Comment: It would be great if you could provide more detail on:
- How the data exactly look like/ is about;
- What are you exactly trying to achieve;
- The errors that you're getting;